# how rmi client cast stub to remote interface type object

Tags: java, client, rmi

i am learning Remote method Invocation 
my question is if how first computer is at one place and another computer is at remote place or on network. how can first computer(client) can cast proxy object (send by remote computer) to remote interface type object how it is possible because interface also present at remote site

Answer (score 0):

The stub implements the remote interface, so the cast is legal by the rules of Java.

The fact that the remote interface also exists at the remote site doesn't make any difference.

Comment: interface  i=(interface)naming.lookup(" ");   how can i make object(reffrence) named "i" on client because client does not know anything about this interface. compiler will give error during compilation

Comment: The remote interface has to be deployed to the client.

Comment: means client have to download either interface 's bytecode or its jar file am i right

Comment: No. It means you have to *deploy* it to the client. Otherwise the client won't run. If you name an interface in a class, that interface has to be present when you execute the class. Otherwise you get a `ClassNotFoundException`. You also have to have the interface available when compiling.

Comment: 'But to deploy it on client' what? What are you talking about?

Comment: "It means you have to deploy it to the client. Otherwise the client won't run."
 how to deploy remote interface on client???

Comment: Same way you deploy all the other class files.

Comment: thanks sir   "http://www.ejbtutorial.com/java-rmi/a-step-by-step-implementation-tutorial-for-java-rmi"   according to this tutorial they create client program in different project but interesting point is that they create again a interface with same name as it present in server project  sir that is the point that is confusing me  should any client (that present at remote site) create interface having same name (as it on remote side) and and as "you say deploy it on client machine".   is it that interface(that client will create) that i need to deploy on machine

Comment: That is poor technique. Create a third project that is common to both server and client, that contains the remote interface and any other application classes that it depends on, and so on. That project must be deployed to both client and server. Once you start copying source code around, anything can happen. Don't do that.